# Does VoiceOver have a links list and heading list similar to JAWS?

Tags: accessibility, voiceover, jaws-screen-reader

In the screen reader, JAWS, pressing `insert + F7` produces a list of links on a web page. Is there a similar function for iOS' VoiceOver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a similar function for iOS VoiceOver?

The only way to know if some links are exposed and select them is to **use the VoiceOver [rotor**](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204783) and choose the links/headings item to move from link/heading to link/heading. [Many other gestures](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/voiceover.html) are also available if need be.

Moreover, as you mentioned JAWS, I suggest you would like to know how to make this kind of feature work with macOS. Take a look at this [Deque University keyboard shortcuts](https://dequeuniversity.com/screenreaders/voiceover-keyboard-shortcuts#vo-mac-the-rotor) and this [commands and gestures reference](https://www.apple.com/voiceover/info/guide/_1131.html) from Apple to get the similar behavior.

Following this rationale, **you can have a links/headings list for your iOS/macOS devices**.

Comment: So basically you won't get the neat little dialogue box that sighted users see when they access the links list in JAWS, but essentially being able to navigate from link-to-link using the voiceover rotor does the same thing for someone who is blind. Looks like the rotor also allows navigating by heading as well which would be the near equivalent of a heading list.

Comment: Also could be helpful: With VoiceOver on in Mac OS (CMD+F5) use the "Rotor" hotkey Ctrl + Option + U. With the rotor open, use the left or right arrows to navigate to different "lists" including landmarks, articles, links and headings.